# Jquery issue : uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, identifier

I got this issue while checking the script code with Chrome.

Here is the code in question :

```
if (!!$.prototype.fancybox)
    $.extend($.fancybox.defaults.tpl, {
        var FancyboxI18nClose = 'CloseBtn';
        var FancyboxI18nNext = 'Next';
        var FancyboxI18nPrev = 'Prev';
        closeBtn : '<a title="' + FancyboxI18nClose + '" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>',
        next     : '<a title="' + FancyboxI18nNext + '" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>',
        prev     : '<a title="' + FancyboxI18nPrev + '" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>'
    });
```

The problematic line is

```
var FancyboxI18nClose = 'CloseBtn';
```

Comment: syntax errors, you cannot declare a variable in a object definition like that

Answer (score 3):

try do following :

```
var FancyboxI18nClose = 'CloseBtn';
var FancyboxI18nNext = 'Next';
var FancyboxI18nPrev = 'Prev';
$.extend($.fancybox.defaults.tpl, {
    closeBtn : '<a title="' + FancyboxI18nClose + '" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>',
    next     : '<a title="' + FancyboxI18nNext + '" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>',
    prev     : '<a title="' + FancyboxI18nPrev + '" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>'
});
```

I means, you have syntax error. You cant declare variables inside objects

Comment: Accept answer, if it correct answer for your question